# iOS 9+ Testflight Cellular Data Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, testflight, nsurlsessiondatatask

I have a mobile iOS app written in Swift 2. Inside the application there is a call to our server through

```
Session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: (func))
```

I have 3 iPads with Cellular data. 1 internal, which I have access to and can hook up to a debugger. 2 external that I have no access to and must ask questions to get an idea of whats going on.

The internal iPad works with build X on both WiFi and Cellular, by works I mean that the request goes through and contacts the server fine.

The external iPads work over WiFi but do not work over cellular.

We have tried

- Ensuring Mobile Data is on, & on for the specific app
- Toggling Airplane mode
- Resetting network
- Restarting Device
- Make sure that the devices actually had a connection when the `dataTaskWithRequest` failed.

Any ideas of what may be going on here? Is there a setting a missed? A setting in the info.plist (why does 1 work) that I've missed?

Comment: Is your server reachable from the external users' cellular network?  You might try checking for blocking by the ISP with a web browser or similar.

Comment: The server is reachable from the browser, this appears to only be a problem with requests coming from the iOS app. There is some rewriting of requests to be redirected happening inside the app, which may be being filtered. Made a new build to capture the response from the server from the users experiencing the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So dgatwood was on the right track.

The requests inside the app were being rerouted to an external server in some cases, and an internal server in other cases. Since these requests originated from WKWebView they had the standard HTTPHeaderFields that come from WKWebView. Since these request were pointing inwards at a mini server written to live in the background of the app these three headers contained incorrect information for the request

- Origin
- Referer
- Host

Over a cooperate data plan there was filtering happening for the requests. Since the origin declared in the header fields did not match the origin of the call, the cellular network was dropping the requests and they were never actually reaching the server.

The issue was corrected by

```
request.setValue(nil, forHTTPHeaderField: "Origin")
request.setValue(nil, forHTTPHeaderField: "Host")
request.setValue(nil, forHTTPHeaderField: "Referer")
```

Hopefully someone finds this helpful at some point